# Run time fault is coming if allocation memory using malloc to store STL list

Tags: c++

I want to create array of list which can store list. so i use `malloc` and get the storage.

```
list<int>*adj;

adj = (list<int>*)malloc(sizeof(list<int>)*v);

adj[0].push_back(1); ==> crash occure in this line...
```

But when is use new operator then it works fine..

```
list<int> *adj;

adj = new list<int>[v];

adj[0].push_back(1); ==> works fine
```

Can somebody help why `malloc` is not working ?

Comment: Never, Never use `malloc` for allocating STL objects!!! use `new`!!!

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`

Comment: Why don't you make a `std::vector<std::list<int>>`?

Comment: i know by using new it works. But i want to know the logic behind. Why malloc is failing ? Am i doing some thing wrong ?

Comment: @user1886358: `malloc` doesn't initialise the memory. It contains garbage, so pretending there's a valid object there won't work. Only use it when you specifically want raw, uninitialised memory (which you generally don't).

Answer (score 2):

Main difference btw allocating memory by `malloc()` and `operator new` - `malloc()` would not call constructor and so your object is not initialized properly. You should not use `malloc()` to create c++ objects unless you have real reason, if you do have one use placement new to initialize object properly.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` only returns a pointer to bytes of uninitialized memory it allocated. That means that you do not actually have a `std::list` object (nothing ever constructed one since `malloc` has no notion of such concepts), but merely a pointer to enough bytes of memory to store a `std::list` object in.

This is different to the line with `new`: `new` allocates enough memory for a `std::list` object and then actually constructs one in this memory. After this construction, you can use the `std::list`, and this construction is *required* for `std::list` to work!

You should not use `malloc` in C++, at least I do not know a single valid usecase for it.

Answer (score 0):

malloc is C function. It ONLY allocates sizeof memory. You should use `new` operator, which will also call list constructor.

Probably list constructor also calls new to allocate some internal data, without calling it you have pointer to corrupted structure.